# Issues with if statements in 'CalAverage' function

Tags: c

I created two if statements to go inside the linked list and check to see how many numbers are above the average and to see how many are below the average. When I run the program to my understanding the if statements are only counting one number. Also, when the program runs, only one of the if statements are called, not both. Maybe I am overlooking something?

```
double CalAverage (NewNumber *start){

int res;
double average = 0;
double total = 0;
int n = 1;
int x = 1;
int y = 1; 

/*if (res != 1){
    fprintf(stderr, "Something bad happened in CalAverage()\n");
    return add;
}*/
while (start->next){
    average += start->newNum;
    start = start->next;
    ++n;
}
average += start->newNum;
total = average/n;
if(total < start->newNum){
        ++x;
        printf("Numbers greater than average: %d\n",x);
    }else if(total > start->newNum){
        ++y;
        printf("Numbers less than average: %d\n", y);
    }
printf("The average is: %lf\n",total);
return total; 
return x;
return y;

}
```

Comment: You have too many return statements; you can only return one value from the function. Only one of the `if` statements can be true (or none, `if total == start->newNum`), so you'll only see output from one of them. You're missing another loop; first you calculate the average, then you'll need to traverse the list again and print for each number if it's above or below the average.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you are losing the pointer to the start of the list by overriding it in the while loop. copy it aside before you start to loop over it.

second, put the if statements in another loop (after re-asigning the start of the list) to count the below/above average.

```
double CalAverage (NewNumber *start){

    double average = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    int n = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0; 

    NewNumber *temp = start;

    while (temp){
        sum += temp->newNum;
        temp = temp->next;
        ++n;
    }

    average = sum / n;

    temp = start;

    while (temp){

        if(average < temp->newNum){
            ++x;
        }else if(average > temp->newNum){
            ++y;
        }

        temp = temp->next;
    }

    printf("The average is: %lf\n",average);
    printf("Numbers greater than average: %d\n",x);
    printf("Numbers less than average: %d\n", y);
    return average; 
}
```

Comment: thank you, I was thinking it if would have created another pointer variable and stuck it inside the while loop, that it would have created another infinite while loop.

Answer (score 0):

The if statements aren't in the while loop, so the function starts, the while loop completes, and then only one if statement is called because it is an if, elseif

Comment: i was going to put them inside the while loop, however total doesn't exist yet in the while loop. I put them into a separate while loop and I caused an infinite while loop. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea why the second while loop is infinite, it's the same as the first loop. There must be something really weird going on behind the scenes.

One way to get around it is to count an index in the first loop so you know how long the second loop should be

Edit: you already have 'n' as the size, which can be an exit condition in the second loop.